# What would the Raychaudhuri Equation be for accelerated geodesics?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, geodesics

What would the [Raychaudhuri Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raychaudhuri_equation) be for accelerated geodesics? Suppose we are not able to assume the geodesic equation but rather have to assume for some tangent vector $u^\alpha$
$$u^\alpha\nabla_\alpha u^\mu = a^\mu$$

Comment: The Raychaudhuri equation works for any timelike vector field representing the flow. It isn't restricted to geodesics.

Comment: Understandably so but, the derivation that I have come across in most of the standard texts makes the assumption of geodesics, any idea how to prove it without the said assumption, i.e. if I consider $u^\alpha \nabla_\alpha u^\mu = a^\mu$ then how do I proceed.